# right size of a custom Buttom created in Photoshop

Tags: android, button, size, photoshop

I created a Layout for my App with the standard UI-Elements. Now i want to create nice Buttons in Photoshop for a better look. So i checked the size for example one Button with Button.getWidth() and getHeight() because i don't want that the Button-Image had to be scaled and it looks pixel. But when i create the Button with the size i became, for example 145x45, the image will be scaled in the app and it looks not good! :-/

what is the problem. How can i make custom Buttons that fit exact for example in an ImageView without scaling?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Greets
Thomas

For Example:

[image]

Comment: So, where is the problem? Create nine patch after the arrow, and there put the text.

Comment: Ok, can you expand the image only on his width...?

Comment: oh sorry i don't see your comment here .... creating a nine-patch after the arrow the text will be stretch too :-/ i don't understand why the size i can read out isn't the right size for the image?!

Answer (score 0):

Do not scale the button. Create nine-patch image and the button will look great at any resolution :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Yes i know...but when i want a button with text inside or other icons for example ... or for example waved border or what ever it don't work with nine-patch ... nine-patch is a great thing,but not for everything :-/ and the button will be scale automatic :-/

Comment: I use nine patch for all my buttons and view and everything is OK..show me an example that this trick do not work.

Comment: i posted an example in my question...what do you think?!

Comment: are you creating 3-4 different sizes to compensate for different screen resolutions/densities?

Comment: i create an app only for a 10.1" Tablet and so the resolution should be the same..

Answer (score 0):

You can load the image in an ImageView with width and height to "wrap_content" and handle the onClicked of the ImageView to use it as a Button.

Comment: Well, he can use a TextView with the image as the background.

Comment: It does, but the image looks to be quite bigger than the text, and the background image will stretch the widget to its size. Of course, using this image for other buttons with longer text, obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: a button mustn't have any text...the big problem is a button with an icon inside

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it will help you. You have created a High Defenition PNG for a button and it is not scaling proberly on your device.

**Solution:** If You have created a larger button image then put it in **XHDPI** folder it may look some what smaller than before else If you want to shrink the image size more put it in **XXHDPI** OR **XXXHDPI** which will work very nice you don't need to create **nine9patch or anything** else. note (Make sure that the image your going to put in **XXHDPI** OR **XXXHDPI** should not be in other **drawable** folder that **PNG** should be in any one folder only)